# next weekend's datetime in javascript returning invalid date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

right now this code works for tomorrow and next month - weekend use to work , except now that it is approaching the end of the month it is causing an error.  my startdate is set to 8/31/12 and enddate is 8/34/12 (which is obivously going to throw an error when converted into DateTime in Sql.)

I am successfully doing math to add a day , and to add a month  , but when it comes to adding days into the next month it breaks.  I think I understand why this is hapening , it is getting date - "29" turning it to into int then adding - I suppose I will get the same problem for "next month" in December.

My question is what is the proper way (or any working way) to add days  to javascript date, where it understands the days of the month.

```
        var d = new Date();
        var startdate;
        var enddate;

         if ($('._tomorrow').attr("checked") == "checked") {
                startdate = [d.getMonth() + 1, d.getDate() + 1, d.getFullYear()].join('/');
                enddate = [d.getMonth() + 1, d.getDate() + 2, d.getFullYear()].join('/');
            }
            if ($('._weekend').attr("checked") == "checked") {
                startdate = [d.getMonth() + 1, d.getDate() + 6 - d.getDay(), d.getFullYear()].join('/');
                enddate = [d.getMonth() + 1, ( d.getDate() + 6 - d.getDay()) + 2, d.getFullYear()].join('/');
            }
            if ($('._nextmonth').attr("checked") == "checked") {
                startdate = [d.getMonth() + 2, 1, d.getFullYear()].join('/');
                enddate = [d.getMonth() + 2, 29 , d.getFullYear()].join('/');
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a specified number of days, create a new `Date` object and then use `d.setDate(d.getDate() + n)` where `n` is the required number of days to add.

If you then call `getYear()`, `getMonth()` and `getDate()` again you will find that they've all been "corrected" to valid values:

```
> d = new Date()
Wed Aug 29 2012 20:57:12 GMT+0100 (BST)
> [d.getDate(), d.getMonth() + 1]
[29, 8]
> d.setDate(d.getDate() + 10);
1347134232993
> [d.getDate(), d.getMonth() + 1]
[8, 9]
```

Adding months is not so straightforward, because you need to define what happens when the following month is shorter than the current month - e.g. what date is "one month after 31st January" ?

Calculating the *start* of the next month is easy enough, though!

```
var now = new Date();
var start = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
var end   = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());

if ($('._tomorrow').is(':checked')) {
    start.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
      end.setDate(now.getDate() + 2);
} else if ($('._weekend').is(':checked')) {
    start.setDate(now.getDate() + 6 - now.getDay());
      end.setDate(now.getDate() + 8 - now.getDay());
} else if ($('._nextmonth').is(':checked')) {
    start.setDate(1);
      end.setDate(1);
    start.setMonth(now.getMonth() + 1);
      end.setMonth(now.getMonth() + 2);
}

var startStr = [start.getMonth() + 1, start.getDate(), start.getFullYear()].join('/');
var endStr = [end.getMonth() + 1, end.getDate(), end.getFullYear()].join('/');
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/nTSMg/

Comment: your's worked as well, pretty much the same, Marc B was faster

Comment: I think Marc's answer is wrong - it tries to produce a specific date one month in the future, not a range containing the entire next whole month (i.e. starting on the 1st).

Comment: i'll check it out , copy and pasting your code from here into mine gave me "8/29/-1788" for today

Comment: @ScottSelby the code has been updated to fix that already - I forgot to call `getFullYear()` instead of `getYear()`

Answer (score 2):

You need to build a new date object with the adjusted values in them. Right now you're simply taking some randomish numbers and increasing them, e.g.

```
31+3/8/2012 -> 34/8/2012, not 3/9/2012
```

Do something like this first:

```
d.setMonth(d.getMonth()+ 2)
```

Internally JS will properly adjust the day/month/years to account for the "overflow" you cause at the end of each period, and still produce a valid date.

Comment: It may be that your not in the javascript chat room talking about brony's that let you give me a quick good answer

Comment: The result of `d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 2)` gives unexpected results if the new month is shorter than the old one (e.g. what date is two months after 31st december?)

Comment: @alnitak: months are a funky concept in dates anyways, especially when you're dealing with February.

Comment: @Alnitak - you're saying this code will stop working in january and Feburary?

Comment: @ScottSelby: no, but `2012-12-31` plus 2 months = `2013-02-31`, - feb 31st doesn't exist, so you'll actually end up with `2012-03-02` - march 2nd, instead.

Comment: oh , that's fine , Next month should really be 09/01/12  , so i'll do something like getMonth() + 1 , so I add 1 month , then subtract getDate() to get the first of the next month

Comment: @ScottSelby no need, just call `setDate(1)` (see my answer)